# Find $y(2) $ given $y(x)$ given a separable differential equation

Tags: calculus

Find what $y(2)$ equals if $y$ is a function of $x$ which satisfies:

$x y^5\cdot y'=1$ given $y=6$ when $x=1$

I got $y(2)=\sqrt{6\ln(2)-46656}$

but this answer is wrong can anyone help me figure out the right answer and how I went wrong?

Comment: please learn how to use mathjax, especially if you post frequently

Comment: I tried to reformat your post...please check that I didn't introduce any errors. A good tutorial on formatting can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Also:  it might help if you showed your work.  That way, people could see where you went awry.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x \, y^5\,  y' = 1 \Rightarrow \\
\int y^5 \, dy = \int \frac{dx}{x} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{6} y^6 = \ln(x) + C \quad (x > 0)
$$
Inserting $y(1) = 6$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{6} 6^6 = \ln(1) + C \Rightarrow \\
C = 6^5
$$
so we got the solution:
$$
y^6 = 6 \ln(x) + 6^6 \quad (x > 0)
$$
which yields
$$
y(2)^6 = 6 \ln(2) + 6^6 \iff \\
y(2) = \left(6 \ln(2) + 6^6\right)^{1/6} = 6.000089135987335\dotsb
$$

Answer (score 0):

This equation is again separable (you would benefit from learning how to solve separable equations as they are the most simple class of differential equations to solve).
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}xy^5=1\Rightarrow y^5dy=x^{-1}dx\Rightarrow \frac{y^6}{6}=\ln(x)+c
$$
Using boundary condition $y(1)=6$ yields
$$ 
\frac{y^6}{6}=\ln(x)+c\Rightarrow \frac{6^6}{6}=\ln(1)+c\Rightarrow 6^5=c
$$
Then we have solution
$$
\frac{y^6}{6}=\ln(x)+6^5
$$
Now you can plug in whatever value you want.